# Error con Controlador en el autoload.php

Tags: php

Tengo un MVC montado, sin usar ningún framework

Si paso por GET un controlador que existe el funcionamiento es correcto, pero si el controlador no existe me da un error al usar el autoload para cargar las clases. En cambio, si cargo las clases de manera manual no me sale ese error

Por ejemplo, si en la URL pongo localhost/MVC/?controller=usuario?action=crear, entonces me carga bien la página. Si el controlador en vez de 'usuario' es otro cualquiera que no existe, por ej 'usuarioo' o 'usuarios' entonces me salta el error

Este es mi index.php

```
//    require_once 'controllers/UsuarioController.php';
require_once 'autoload.php';

if(isset($_GET['controller']))
    $nombre_controlador = $_GET['controller'] . 'Controller';

if(isset($_GET['controller']) && class_exists($nombre_controlador))
{
    $controlador = new $nombre_controlador();
    
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && method_exists($controlador, $_GET['action']))
    {
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        $controlador->$action();
    }
    else
        echo "La página que buscas no existe<br>Falta segundo parámetro (action) o el action indicado NO existe";
}
else
    echo "La página que buscas no existe<br>Falta primer parámetro (controller) o el controller indicado NO existe";
```

Este es mi autoload.php

```
    function autocargar($classname)
    {
        if(file_exists('controllers/' . $classname . '.php'))
            include 'controllers/' . $classname . '.php';
    }

    spl_autoload_register('autocargar');
```

Este es mi UsuarioController.php

```
    class UsuarioController
    {
        public function crear()
        {
            echo "Crear usuario";
        }
    
        public function listar()
        {
            echo "Listado de todos los usuarios";
        }
    }
```

El index.php y el autoload.php están en raíz y el UsuarioController.php están en una carpeta llamada controllers

Si en vez de usar autolad.php cargo las clases manualmente una a una con require_once entonces no me sale ese error

Cómo evito ese error con el autolad.php?

Gracias!

Comment: Has probado a hacer un maincontroller que sea el que se encargue de crear el controlador que recibes? Me da que esto es porque este index no tiene namespace, y realmente no lo necesita. Ese maincontroller ya debería tener el namespace correspondiente y podría utilizar clases de otros namespaces

Comment: si este `if (isset($_GET['controller']) && class_exists($nombre_controlador))` no te esta evitando que llame una clase que no existe siempre existe el `try ... catch`

Comment: Probaré con un try ... catch. Sobre lo del maincontroller que sea el que se encargue de crear el controlador que se recibe por GET, cómo se haría?

Answer (score 0):

Ya está editado. Solamente hay que añadir una condición if() en el autoload.php para preguntar si existe el archivo en el directorio indicado. Si existe se hace el include y si no nada. Con eso evito el error.